# Pointer address value truncated

Tags: c, gdb

I am facing core dump issue in my application code, application got dumped in frequent intervals(once in a month, not exactly). During the core analysis , i am able to identify that corrupted pointer is truncated.

For example: Normal addresses are looks to be *0x7f8cf23da8b0* and *0x7f8cf23da8b8* etc(addresses having 12 octets ). but corrupted address looks like *0x7f8cf23da8*(only 10 octets i am seeing from the dump file, last two octets missing).

one more observation is, Some times address looks to be odd number(some thing like *0x7f8cf23da8c9*), i didnt expect as 64 bit alignment is in place. Please clarify if this kind of address is valid?

Can some one clarify what is the possibility of address could truncate such way also clarify that odd address is possible/valid?

system: RHEL 7.2

Src code Language: C

dpdk huge pages are in place

Comment: Is this your application, for which you have the source code? If not, then contact the supplier / developer.

Comment: @Attie , yes this is my application

Comment: Are you able to identify a code path that causes the issue? Can you reproduce the issue with an MCVE?

Comment: Issue is not reproducible locally. yes i know the code path and corruption corruption point aswel. i did analysis on my code as much as possible, and corruption is not done by the software, is that i concluded. My question is how come the pointer has been *truncated*. bcoz if it over written i will get atlease some junk value, not the truncated one.

when system is over loaded and processes are swapping in and out , to the processor registers may cause these kind of problem?

Comment: I don't think it's been truncated, but perhaps right-shifted 8-bits... or perhaps you're doing pointer arithmetic and getting it wrong by one... I would be _very_ surprised if this was an issue with the Kernel / scheduler, it's most likely going to be something in your application or a library that you use.

Comment: @Attie yeah it may not be system related(kernel/scheduler) issue, bocz every time crash is seen in particular area. Application is doing pointer arithmetic ONLY during the initialization part, if it goes wrong then application may not wait 30 days to crash. 

yeah i was thinking right shift case wel, but i code i couldnt find such overwrite or operation, since no pointer arithmetic after init. Anyway, Thanks for your hints, let me debug more , meanwhile u can also update if you could get some direction. Thanks

Comment: Again, i would like to explain some more details. my application has a "shared memory" which is shared between 2 active processes(let say p1, p2). P1 having read write access to this shared memory where as P2 has Read only access. 

Now P1 got frequently Crashed as explained in the question and when i analyzing the core dump , some pointer has  been corrupted. Later when i wrote a debug tool(along with Process 2) to dump the shared memory, i dont  see any corrupted pointers/values in the shared memory. for me P1 involves is high speed dpdk data processing and P2 doing some cleanups.